# "pythonshell in" node failing because there's an apostrophe in the output

Tags: python, node-red

I'm using a Python script which returns the currently playing/on air DJs on the BBC at the moment. Thought it was working error free but now I find it fails if there's a (weird) apostrophe "’" in the output. Can I fix this somehow?

```
exit code: 1, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script2.py", line 17, in <module>
    print g_data[5].text
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

this is the output

```
Clara Amfo
Radio 1 Dance
Ace
Ken Bruce
Essential Classics
Hip-hop’s Laughing Stock
Desert Island Discs Revisited
The Emma Barnett Show
Cricket
Mary Anne Hobbs
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64701464/edit) the question to include the script so we can see what is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `’` that you have in your string is not ascii. The ascii equivalent is `'`, note the difference.

Getting unicode errors when printing is common in Python, and what you need to do is encode the string before you print it.

eg.

```
print g_data[5].text.encode('utf-8')
```

More information can be found in the Python documentation - https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type